# Maven build single JAR with packaged dependencies

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to build a single jar with packaged dependencies inside it e.g. mysql connector.
My code in pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
```

```
                <version>3.3.0</version>
```

```
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
```

```
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
```

```
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I receive the following message

*Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project DemoProject: Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar' not found*

Comment: Please read the documentation because `<descriptorRef>..</descriptorRef>` is not a reference to a jar file it's a reference to an xml descriptor (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) ... furthermore I strongly recommend to define the version of maven-assembly-plugin because the given version is ancient...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I corrected my code for anyone else who may need it.